# RichEditBox: Using CTRL+I to set italic text deletes the text

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, richtextbox, rtf

I have the following code to bold and italicise text in a RichEditBox:

```
private async void Page_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var state = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control);
    if ((state & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.B:
                await BoldText();
                break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.I:
                await ItaliciseText();
                break;
        }
    }
}

private async Task BoldText()
{
    ITextSelection selectedText = editor.Document.Selection;
    if (selectedText != null)
    {
        ITextCharacterFormat charFormatting = selectedText.CharacterFormat;
        charFormatting.Bold = FormatEffect.Toggle;
        selectedText.CharacterFormat = charFormatting;
    }
}

private async Task ItaliciseText()
{
    ITextSelection selectedText = editor.Document.Selection;
    if (selectedText != null)
    {
        ITextCharacterFormat charFormatting = selectedText.CharacterFormat;
        charFormatting.Italic = FormatEffect.Toggle;
        selectedText.CharacterFormat = charFormatting;
    }
}
```

`BoldText()` and `ItaliciseText()` are also called from buttons on a toolbar.

When `Bold` is pressed, the selected text is formatted to Bold text correctly.

When `CTRL+B` is pressed, the selected text is formatted to Bold text correctly.

When `Italic` is pressed, the selected text is formatted to Italic text correctly

When `CTRL+I` is pressed, the selected text is formatted to Italic text correctly, **but then deleted**

I know the formatting is happening because if I press CTRL+Z the text returns in italics. CTRL+I is causing an additional operation after `selectedText.CharacterFormat = charFormatting;` which wipes the text.

I can't figure out why this is happening as the code is almost identical to the flawless BoldText() code and words perfectly when fired from a button on the toolbar.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl+I` may have another handler on it (which might be one causing text deleted), consider setting `KeyRoutedEventArgs.Handled = true;`, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs.ASPx), (in this case `e.Handled=true;`) when you don't want this KeyEvent to be handled else where other than yours.

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't use, it's a good tool, and can download it easily
http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/sites/introduction/?gclid=CPTaj_LQh7wCFcJd3godZA4AZg